# Как доработать функцию для окончаний слов

Tags: php

Есть функция 'вывода окончаний':

```
function plural_type($n) {return ($n%10==1 && $n%100!=11 ? 0 : ($n%10>=2 && $n%10<=4 && ($n%100<10 || $n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2));}
    $_plural_msg = array('сообщение', 'сообщения', 'сообщений');
    $_plural_piple = array('человек', 'человека', 'человек');
    $_plural_comm = array('комментарий', 'комментария', 'комментариев');
    $_plural_zap = array('запись', 'записи', 'записей');
```

Вызывается например следующим образом:

```
echo 'В группе - '.$_plural_piple[plural_type($row["count"])];
```

Для этого дела создано 4 массива. Но что-то не даёт мне покоя. То ли не оптимизировано это как-то, то ли массивы рациональнее внутрь функции **plural_type** запихать? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно модифицировать эту функцию на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Ну я бы просто передавал возможные варианты слов в функцию..